# Why might my connection to this remote server be dropping?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ssh, vpn, openvpn

I am not a sysadmin nor have a large background in networking, so I may be missing something very obvious here.

I am trying to connect to a remote server through a VPN provided by my work with SSH and am encountering random, 30-60 drops in connection on what is otherwise a perfectly good connection. This isn't latency so much as one second I am experiencing a good connection the next the connection has dropped.

For reference, I am on a Thinkpad T450 running Fedora 33. All my packages and drivers are up to date to the best of my knowledge.

Here is what I know:

- another employee near the server's facility is able to ssh into the server with no issue, however they are on Windows 10
- my internet connection outside of this context is perfectly fine; I don't have connection issues streaming Netflix, browsing the internet, connecting to other servers, etc.
- there are no intermediaries between me and the server; `traceroute` shows only my network gateway and the server
- the server is running on OpenVPN 2.5, while I am stuck on OpenVPN 2.4.10 as a 2.5 build has not been released on Fedora
- it is a UDP connection, I am going to try TCP later today
- running `mtr`for ~10 minutes displays ~50% packet loss
- `ping`, `mtr`, and `traceroute` all display behavior where packets are being consistently send for a couple of minutes - then randomly fail to connect for ~30-60 seconds - then resume where they were

I have reached the limits of my knowledge on what else to do in this situation, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you have packet loss to other destinations through the VPN or only to that specific server? Does mtr report packet loss to the VPN server itself, for its internal address (through the VPN) and the external address directly? Does the OpenVPN client log anything related to restarting the handshake?

Answer (score 0):

Not a very exciting answer, but making a VPN config file that chooses an unused local port at random appears to have fixed the issue.